# Is that possible to hide the stage in gitlab ci workflow?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to make the stage `uninterruptible` that runs the `uninterruptible_job` invisible (for `master` and `release/v` branches). Is there any function in gitlab ci to make that work ?

```yaml
stages:
  - uninterruptible
  - pre_check
  - build
  - assign_test
  - host_test
  - deploy

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^release\/v/ && $CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ /^v\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?($|-)/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS != null
      variables:
        PIPELINE_COMMIT_SHA: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA
    - if: $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS == null
      variables:
        PIPELINE_COMMIT_SHA: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - when: always

before_script:
  - echo "Before script is started here"

default:
  interruptible: true
  retry:
    max: 2
    when:
      - always

uninterruptible_job:
  stage: uninterruptible
  interruptible: false
  resource_group: production
  script:
    - echo "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is uninterruptible"
  tags:
    - assign_test
  rules:
    - if:  '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^release\/v/'
      when: always


include:
  - '.gitlab/ci/pre_check.yml'
  - '.gitlab/ci/build.yml'
  - '.gitlab/ci/assign_test.yml'
  - '.gitlab/ci/host_test.yml'
  - '.gitlab/ci/deploy.yml'
```

Comment: What do you mean "hide" the stage? Like you don't want it to run? Or?

Comment: I want it to run but not be visible in the gitlab pipeline's UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no feature of GitLab to hide jobs visibly in the UI.

You can delete job traces and artifacts or [delete entire pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#delete-a-pipeline) (like after they finish running), but there is no way to just hide stages or jobs in GitLab's pipeline visualization UI.